# Renaming a Pandas Dataframe column and Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

```
student_data.rename(columns={"date_Of_Birth":"dob"}, inplace=True)
student_data.head()
```

I have tried it with both with and without inplace but still it is not working.
And another problem is with groupby function

```
student_data.groupby(student_data.loc[:,'date_Of_Birth'].dt.year)
```

Using groupby I am getting keyerror, even though the column has not been renamed to dob from date_Of_Birth.

Comment: Verify the name of your columns. The most likely error is what it says - you do not have a column called `date_Of_Birth`. We can't verify that for you - you need to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that illustrates the problem.

Comment: "not working" isn't very informative. Can you show your df before and after? If it's too big, make a smaller df to include a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Please add a sample of input `student_data` as code, for example `student_data.head().to_dict()`

Comment: Looks as though you have made a typo. The code will work if column is correctly named as used in the rename function.

Answer (score 0):

First, confirm that the column is there and that it is named exactly as you expect:

```
print(student_data.columns)
```

This will give you a list of all the column names in student_data.

If the column name is "date_Of_Birth", then ensure it is a datetime type:

```
print(student_data['date_Of_Birth'].dtype)
```

If it is not a datetime object, you will need to convert it:

```
student_data['date_Of_Birth'] = pd.to_datetime(student_data['date_Of_Birth'])
```

Now, you can group by the year:

```
grouped = student_data.groupby(student_data['date_Of_Birth'].dt.year)
```